# Permissions with Facebook Login - publish_actions permission not getting

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my website, users can post to their FB wall from my website. I,am using graph api for that. My api code is,

```
       FB.api(
            "/me/photos",
            "POST",
            {
                "caption": "My caption",
                "url": "My image url"
            },
            function (response) {  console.log(response);
              if (response && !response.error) {
                $('#post_response').html('<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='+response.id+'" target="_blank">See feed</a>');
              }
            }
        );
```

During this api call getting an error,

```
code: 200
message: "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions"
type: "OAuthException"
```

My Fb login Api is,

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    },
      {
        scope: 'email,public_profile,publish_actions,manage_pages',
        auth_type: 'rerequest',
        return_scopes: true
      }
    );
```

I also tried,

```
1)
FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    },
      {
        scope: 'publish_actions'
      }
    );


2)
FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    },
      {
        scope: 'publish_actions',
        auth_type: 'rerequest'
      }
    );
```

By calling api,

```
FB.api("/me/permissions", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I understood that, only getting 'email,public_profile' permissions.

How to get 'publish_actions' permission??

Is there any other methods to do this??  I want to post image post to users wall and users page...

Please help me to fix this issue...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the FB account to test user under FB app settings >test user . Because In order to use permissions like publish _action your app needs to be approved by Facebook,but with test users you can test the functionalities.

Comment: Thank you...and my conclusion is,
If we want to post to users wall or page, we need 'publish_actions' permission. 
   This permission will be granted only after our fb app submited for review.
 
   People listed as Admins, Developers or Testers within the Roles section of your app dashboard can fully test the app, 
   and request any permissions, without submitting it for review.